# How can we partition data in ODI 12c?

Tags: database-partitioning, oracle-data-integrator

I have a source table of around 100 million of data. I need to partition my source data into 10 partitions of 10 million each and run the mapping with 10 partitions parallelly.

How do I proceed with this for the desired result, as I need to optimize my work flow for faster processing?

I have tried including filter and creating scenario's and running them parallelly using **ASYNCHRONOUS MODE** in ODI12c, but in this use case I do not have any condition on which I can partition. If it is possible to partition on ROWNUM wise,  how to proceed with this?

Comment: We're not all from India and therefore using Indian words like crore will definitely confuse people

Comment: Hi Arif Ali, I have the next questions: 1. your source it's a query or it's a simple table? 2. Do you have a primary key on the source table? 3. What datatype this table have? 4. You can filter the source on some date column? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Lazarescu,1. Its a table with huge amount of data say 100 Million ,2. Yes there is a primary key on the table , 3. This table has VARCHAR and NUMERIC but most of them are VARCHAR , 4. There is a column with date i can filter based on year by taking substring of it.

Comment: Hi Arif, see if this article helps you in your use case..
https://www.ateam-oracle.com/using-oracle-partition-exchange-with-oracle-data-integrator-odi